# Laravel 5 badmethodcallexceltiopn with model database query builder

Tags: laravel-5, model

I'm having a problem with a bad method call exception, the error is this

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lugars()
in Builder.php line 2443
at Builder->__call('lugars', array()) in Builder.php line 1239
at Builder->lugars() in Builder.php line 1239
```

I was told once that the problem was not defining the tables name in the MODEL, BUT it is in the model, so I don't see what's the problem

here is the model: 
`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Lugar extends Model
{
    //
     protected $table = 'lugares';

     public function Lugares(){

        return $this-> belongsTo('App\Empresa');
    }
    public function Users(){

        return $this-> belongsToMany('App\User','lugares_usuarios', 'user_id', 'lugar_id');
    }
}
```

`

i think the problem is on the Lugares model, since it is the only place where the protected $table is...

any clues on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

you call method relation with name `lugars` although it's name in the model is `Lugares`

just spilling mistake

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to fix it, the problem is that laravel uses english so he assumes sometimes the names and that is why it adds the S at the end.

but the thing is when I put protected tables, it is supposed to modify the name so it would not use the default procedure of naming. 

so how can I tell him to not use that procedure and use my custom name of the table?

Comment: you miss the character `e` in the name `lugars`  it must be `lugares`